# Take a input value from input tag which is iterating on For loop

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

There is a Subscription plan which is iterating on the loop [image: cards are generated over loop] where the user can add the Add-on's. On click of Add-on Button i am taking the input from the user to add more cloud accounts or increase the users for the application [image: With Add-on's]. 
As the input tag is iterating over array how to read the value from the input tag for different plans and i am checking the condition if the user checks the checkbox he can edit the input tag else it will be disabled. if i check any checkbox it is affecting all the checkbox and the input tag over the array.

My question is how to check the condition of the checkbox and enable the input tag and how to read the values for each different plans which is iterating over array.

**HTML CODE:**

```
 <div class="content content-full">
   <div class="container-fluid main-panel" [ngClass]="(globals.accountMenuDisplay === 'block')?'':'main_70'">
      <div class='pricing pricing-palden animated fadeIn' style="padding-top: 10px">
          <div *ngFor="let plans of ProductPlanDetailResponse;let i = index" [ngClass]="(i%2==0)?'pricing-item':'pricing-item pricing__item--featured'">
            <div class='pricing-deco' >
            <svg class='pricing-deco-img' enable-background='new 0 0 300 100' height='100px' id='Layer_1' preserveAspectRatio='none' version='1.1' viewBox='0 0 300 100' width='300px' x='0px' xml:space='preserve' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' y='0px'>
              <path class='deco-layer deco-layer--1' d='M30.913,43.944c0,0,42.911-34.464,87.51-14.191c77.31,35.14,113.304-1.952,146.638-4.729&#x000A;   c48.654-4.056,69.94,16.218,69.94,16.218v54.396H30.913V43.944z' fill='#FFFFFF' opacity='0.6'></path>
              <path class='deco-layer deco-layer--2' d='M-35.667,44.628c0,0,42.91-34.463,87.51-14.191c77.31,35.141,113.304-1.952,146.639-4.729&#x000A;  c48.653-4.055,69.939,16.218,69.939,16.218v54.396H-35.667V44.628z' fill='#FFFFFF' opacity='0.6'></path>
              <path class='deco-layer deco-layer--3' d='M43.415,98.342c0,0,48.283-68.927,109.133-68.927c65.886,0,97.983,67.914,97.983,67.914v3.716&#x000A;  H42.401L43.415,98.342z' fill='#FFFFFF' opacity='0.7'></path>
              <path class='deco-layer deco-layer--4' d='M-34.667,62.998c0,0,56-45.667,120.316-27.839C167.484,57.842,197,41.332,232.286,30.428&#x000A;   c53.07-16.399,104.047,36.903,104.047,36.903l1.333,36.667l-372-2.954L-34.667,62.998z' fill='#FFFFFF'></path>
            </svg>
            <div class='pricing-price'><span class='pricing-currency'>$</span>{{plans.recurringPrice}}
              <span class='pricing-period'>/ month</span>
            </div>
            <h3 class='pricing-title'>{{plans.planName}}</h3>
            </div>

            <h4  style="font-size: 2em; color:#00373e; margin-top: -30px; z-index:11" class="pricing-price">Features</h4>
              <ul  style="padding: 10px;list-style: none;">
                <li *ngFor="let features of plans.planDescription;let j = index" style="padding: 5px">
                    {{features}}
                </li>
              </ul>
              <div [ngStyle]="{'display':addAddons}">
                <div >
                  <input type ="checkbox" (change)="enableCloudAccounts()" >
                  <input class="custom-input"  id="cloudAccount{{j}}" type="text" [disabled]="noOfCloudAccount==false ? true : null" placeholder=" # of Cloud Account" style="margin: 5px">
                </div>
                <div >
                    <input type ="checkbox" (change)="enableUsers()" >
                    <input class="custom-input" type="text" [disabled]="noOfUsers==false ? true : null" placeholder=" # of Users" style="margin: 5px">
                  </div>
              </div>
              <button class='pricing-action' (click)="enableAddons()">{{addonText}}</button>
              <button class='pricing-action'>Choose plan</button>

          </div>
          </div>


    </div>
```

**TypScript File** :

```
      noOfCloudAccount : any;
      noOfUsers : any;
      addAddons: any;
      addonText: any;
ngOnInit() {
    this.noOfCloudAccount= false;
    this.noOfUsers = false;
    this.addAddons = 'none';
    this.addonText = 'Add Addons';
}
enableCloudAccounts(){
  this.noOfCloudAccount = !this.noOfCloudAccount;
}
enableUsers(){
  this.noOfUsers = !this.noOfUsers;
}
enableAddons(){
  this.addAddons = 'block';
}
```

[StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xuj4ja)

Comment: You have to create an array and bind them each seperately

Comment: My question is how to bind those separately . @AvinKavish

Comment: You need to user formArray and for making it simple create a component for the `plan item` and use binding, please create a stackblitz so people can help you better

Comment: @RezaRahmati i have added StackBlitz link check above.